# Limiting Access to a Specific Page By Requiring Sequential Order of Page Views

Tags: php, security

I am trying to limit page access so that the user must enter the page in question by clicking a button on 1 of 3 pages.

So, to be clear, page x can only be accessed if the user clicks a button from page 1, 2, or 3.

I've tried using `isset` if/`else` blocks, but cannot seem to make any progress with limiting the page access in this way. If anyone has any suggestions I'd be very grateful!

Comment: What did you do with isset that did not work?

Comment: Cookies, Session Varibiles, encoded URLs... take your pick

Comment: @McKracken Basically just `isset($_POST['button1'])` type if statements where button 1 is the page before it that is supposed to requrie sequential access to get to the other page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use sessions ...

for example

```
session_start();
$_SESSION=array();
```

in each page add a value to the array

```
 $_SESSION['page1']="viewed";
 $_SESSION['page2']="viewed";
```

In your secured page check the elements of the `$_SESSION` array

Answer (score 0):

Set a cookie when said button is clicked, and check for that cookie when that page is visited.